# Dataset enviado de uma classe para outra

Tags: c#, asp.net

Existe algum componente `Ado` equivalente a um `recordset` que eu possa enviar de uma classe para outra em c#?

Comment: Normalmente, é capaz enviar qualquer classe para qualquer outra classe em C#, por meio do constructor. Tem um exemplo do que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: Mas eu não posso fazer por construtor, pois seria uma classe genérica.

Comment: Tem outras maneiras também, sendo por *properties* e *templates*, etc. Poderia fornecer um pouco mais de contexto (por exemplo, código-fonte ou alguma tentativa que já fez) para poder entender melhor a sua dúvida?